# Group div elements by dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `day` class dynamic:

```
<div class="day day111">a</div>
<div class="day day111">a</div>
<div class="day day112">a</div>
<div class="day day112">a</div>
<div class="day day113">a</div>
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="day day111">a</div>
     <div class="day day111">a</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="day day112">a</div>
    <div class="day day112">a</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="day day113">a</div>
</div>
```

I can only do this in javascript. I'm trying with a loop, but I can not group. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Are these divs in the right order originally, or can those “days” come in any order?

Comment: Do you know what is the limits of that number? Does it always start with 111? How many groups there can be at maximum?

Comment: The 111 is the unix data format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var groups = {};
$('.day').each(function () {
    var className = this.className.match(/(day\d+)/)[1],
        $group = groups[className];
    if (!$group) {
        $group = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'group'
        }).insertAfter(this);
        groups[className] = $group;
    }
    $group.append(this);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H6wHR/)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

```
$('#box1 >div.day').each(function(){
   var cls = (this.className);

    var group = groups[cls];
    if(!group)
    {
    group = $('<div/>').appendTo('#box2');
    group.addClass('group');

    groups[cls] = group;
    }

    $(this).appendTo(group);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p3YTS/2/