# Group divs by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949400/group-div-elements-by-dynamic-class) I try to group divs by its div attribute "messsage-id".
So all divs with the same "message-id" should be wrapped by a div with class name group.

```
<div class="message" message-id="1">a</div>
<div class="message" message-id="1">a</div>
<div class="message" message-id="2">a</div>
<div class="message" message-id="2">a</div>
<div class="message" message-id="3">a</div>
```

But I dont get it to work with attributes instead of class names. Here is what I tried:

```
var groups = {};
$('.day').each(function () {
    var className = this.getAttribute("message-id").match(/(day\d+)/)[1],
        $group = groups[className];
    if (!$group) {
        $group = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'group'
        }).insertAfter(this);
        groups[className] = $group;
    }
    $group.append(this);
})
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpmzubtg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path with the `getAttribute` function but don't need the use the `match` function in your code since `getAttribute` already returns the id for your groups. Also, your `$('.day')` is not targeting the right class for your loop, it should be targeting `$('.message')` in your example.

```js
var groups = {};
$('.message').each(function () { 
    var className = this.getAttribute("message-id"),
    $group = groups[className];
    if (!$group) {
        $group = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'group'
        }).insertAfter(this);
        groups[className] = $group;
    }
    $group.append(this);
})
```

```css
.group {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message day" message-id="1">a</div>
<div class="message day" message-id="1">a</div>
<div class="message day" message-id="2">a</div>
<div class="message day" message-id="2">a</div>
<div class="message day" message-id="3">a</div>
```